# socket io emit generating Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: javascript, sockets

I am getting the following error

```
C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\node_modules\cycle\cycle.js:62
                !(value instanceof String)) {
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

on my

```
 return io.to(socket.id).emit('friendsInvited', data);
```

line.
I have this same code a number of places in but the error only occurs in this block of code....see below:

```
       socket.on('inviteFriends', function(body) {
                let inviteesArr = body.split(',');
                let emailObjArray = validateInvitees(body)
                console.log("EmailObj Array: " + JSON.stringify(emailObjArray));

                if (emailObjArray.length === 0) {

                    data = {
                        code: String = '1',
                        msg: String = 'failmessage...'
                    };
   **<<FAILS HERE>>**   return io.to(socket.id).emit('friendsInvited', data);
                } else
                {
                 ...function(a,b,f(c){
                      if (x===0) {} else
                       {
    **<<WORKS HERE>>**   return io.to(socket.id).emit('friendsInvited', data);
                       }
              }}
.......
```

data is always the same data.code and data.msg. This construct works in many other places except in this code block. I figure I am missing something very basic but cannot see it. I thought I was having a scope issue but I don't thinks so.
EDIT: here is more stacktrace.....

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
    at derez (C:\path\app\node_modules\cycle\cycle.js:62:25)
    at Object.decycle (C:\path\app\node_modules\cycle\cycle.js:101:6)
    at Object.exports.clone (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\common.js:97:22)
    at Object.exports.log (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\common.js:149:19)
    at exports.Console.Console.log (C:\\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\console.js:99:19)
    at exports.Console.Transport.logException (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\transport.js:134:8)
    at logAndWait (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:649:15)
    at C\path\app\\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:157:13
    at _each (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:57:9)
    at Object.async.each (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:156:9)
    at exports.Logger.Logger._uncaughtException (C:\path\app\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:672:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:378:26)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
....
```

Comment: This looks like an error in the winston module, a logger (or cycle) Try updating: `npm update`

Comment: @Chris G ...Nope that didn't do it....same errors

Comment: @Chris  I also install winston 3.0..that broke the code....so I settled on  2.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit lies here:

```
data = {
  code: String = '1',
  msg: String = 'failmessage...'
};
```

You are basically overriding the built-in `String` constructor.

Example:

```
const x = String = 'something';
```

`x` will equal `'something'`, but that's the result returned from the `String = 'something'` assignment which in fact changes the built-in `String` constructor. Now when you try to use `variableName instanceof String`, `String` will be a primitive value, but `instanceof` can only be used with a constructor function as a right hand side - and thus the error thrown by the runtime.

Comment: ...you have an eagle eye in addition your explanation taught me something I wasn't paying attention to...great job